# Setting up the crontab job for Google App Engine

Tags: git, google-app-engine, gcloud

I'm trying to auto deploy my app from the Google App Engine. So I set up a crontab job directly from the Google Cloud Shell for this task. It would check if there are any incoming pushes to the master of the git, and it would automatically pull the changes and auto deploy the app.

The pulling process is fine. My problem is that when executing shell from the crontab, it would call `gcloud app deploy` to deploy the app int the app directory. However it would prompts that it would need auth login to deploy the app. But If I directly call `gcloud app deploy` it's working fine.

So I want to know how to avoid the auth login process in the crontab job if I want to call gcloud commands.
`

Comment: You *might* be able to use the `gcloud auth activate-service-account` cmd https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/activate-service-account

Answer (score 0):

Each user on the machine has their own gcloud config directory which contains their own set of credentials. It is likely that your crontab is running as a root user that is not using the same config as when you login manually. You need to login as the user that the crontab is running as.

That being said, it is unlikely that this strategy is going to work for you. Cloud shell is meant for interactive use through the browser and disconnects after periods of inactivity. You will not be able to run persistent automated processes from there.